# Sharing a USB Modem's Internet with Raspberry Pi

Tags: networking

I use internet using USB Modem that I want to share with my raspberry pi. I have a raspberry pi 3 model B. I have gone through the previous posts on how to share internet from windows pc, by opening up the network and sharing center, and properties. I have done all that, and restarted the computer. I am connecting my rpi using ethernet cable. My network and sharing center looks like this.

[image: network and sharing]

The network GP-Internet is my internet connection. And its sharing tab in properties looks like this.

[image]

But when I run this command from my pi

`ping www.google.com`

I get no reply. How to share internet to my pi. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This appears to be a question about Windows

Comment: Should I post it on stackoverflow?

Comment: I would post this on https://superuser.com